# Laravel Symbolic Link in Shared hosting problem

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, symlink

I am using shared hosting.
I have installed my laravel application and i am using unisharp Laravel File Manager.

With the manager, I uploaded file "happy.jpg". it produced url "http://unpluggedworldofmine.com/storage/photos/1/happy.jpg" but i cannot access to the file.

instead, when i use 
"http://unpluggedworldofmine.com//storage/app/public/photos/1/happy.jpg", i can see that i has been uploaded properly.

it looks like there is problem with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

AS i am using shared hosting, i cannot change configuration in httd or others.

i used

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to set up link.

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks